# Bootstrap display async image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to website development. I am using bootstrap and trying to display a image control. Here's the code snippet:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Sierpinski_square.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"/>
</div>
```

The **above code can display the image correctly**. But if I switch to this:

```
<div id="post-image" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
</div>
```

and use a JQuery control (https://github.com/websanova/wScratchPad) to load the image like this:

```
$( window ).load(function() {
    $('#post-image').wScratchPad({
      bg: 'path/to/image',
      fg: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Sierpinski_square.jpg',
      'cursor': 'url("path/to/image") 5 5, default'
    });
});
```

I see the image can be loaded, but cannot be displayed properly. The image height become 1 and is displayed like this:

[image]

I am wondering if I am doing anything wrong and caused HTML couldn't refresh according to the downloaded image size? Thank you

Comment: give the img a min-height in css

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things.

1. You don't need both the col-md-12 and col-xs-12. The classes are bottom up, meaning col-xs will display for xs to lg. You would only need the md tag if you want it to display differently in medium sizes.
2. Set a style="min-height:..." on the div to the image's height.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the css min-height property, and it works. But my concern is how to avoid hard-coded min-height pixels in this case? Hard coding the min-height to be some pixel value will make it not responsive.

Comment: Attaching the image to a div makes it very tough to set the div's height without the images height explicitly set. Try setting the min-height to 100% and see how it looks.